# React: How to know which component calls the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing my first project using React and there is one thing I can't figure out. So I have many different `Type` components which are being set as the main component's `TypesPage` state. And when the `onChange` event happens on `Type` component I want to know which type it is in a `TypesPage` state or what index it is in a types array, so I can reupdate my `data` state.

Inside `handleChange` function I used jQuery's grep function comparing clicked `Type` title value with all the types array, but I am sure that is not the right way to do it and it would be an overkill with huge arrays.

Why I want to know which

```js
handleChange:function(element, event){
  var typeIndex;
  $.grep(types, function(e, index){
    if(element.title === e.title){
      typeIndex = index
    }
  });
  types[typeIndex] //Now I know that this is the Type that was changed
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5kvdywrb/2/)

```js
var types = [
  {
    type_id: 1,
    type_name: "Logo"
  },
  {
    type_id: 2,
    type_name: "Ad"
  },
  {
    type_id: 3,
    type_name: "Catalog"
  },
];

var Type = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return( 
        <li>
        <input type="text" value={this.props.title}
            onChange={this.props.handleChange.bind(null, this.props)} />
      </li>
    );
  }
});
var TypesContainer = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var that = this;
      return(
        <ul>
            {this.props.data.map(function(entry){
            return(
                <Type
                key={entry.type_id}
                title={entry.type_name}
                handleChange={that.props.handleChange}
              />
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      );       
  }
});
var TypesPage = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return({data: types})
  },
  handleChange: function(element, event){

  },
  render: function() {
    return(
        <TypesContainer
            data={this.state.data}
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <TypesPage />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer ES6. The problem is, you have to `bind` your `handleChange` event with correct context of `this` and pass your arguments which you are expect to get inside your handle. See example below

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        data: [{id: 1, type: 'Hello'},{id: 2, type: 'World'},{id: 3, type: 'it"s me'}],
      focusOn: null
    };

  } 
  change(index,e){
    const oldData = this.state.data;
    oldData[index].type = e.target.value;
    this.setState({data:oldData, focusOn: index})
  }
  render(){
    const list = this.state.data.map((item,index) => 
        // this is the way how to get focused element 
        <input key={item.id} value={item.type} onChange={this.change.bind(this, index)}/>  
    );
    return <div>
        {list}
      <p>Focused Element with index: {this.state.focusOn}</p>
    </div>
  }
}
React.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

[`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/387/)

Thanks

Comment: Oh Wow :) It's amazing... so it has nothing to do with React, just my poor understanding of javascript. Thank you!